# ExtJS 5 Build Error (ExBuild: Failed to compress input)

Tags: extjs, extjs5, sencha-cmd, antbuilder

I have some build errors when try to build my ExtJS application (My OS is Windows 7)

app.framework.version=5.0.0.970

app.cmd.version=5.0.0.160

Building failed with an exception: "com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild"
Can you help me to solve this problem?

```
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed to compress input
[ERR]   at java.util.regex.Patte
[ERR] rn$GroupTail.match(Unknown Source)
[ERR]   at java
[ERR] .util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Unknown Source)
[ERR]   at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Unknown Sourc
[ERR] e)
[ERR]   at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Un
[ERR] known Source)
[ERR]   at java.util.regex.Patter
[ERR] n$Branch.match(Unknown Source)
[ERR]   at java.util.rege
[ERR] x.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Unknown Source)
[ERR]
[ERR]   at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Unk
[ERR] nown Source)
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 21 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Users\admin\workspaceKepler\Propca\WebContent\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:390: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Users\admin\workspaceKepler\Propca\WebContent\.sencha\app\page-impl.xml:202: com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed to compress input
```

The related lines of Build-impl.xml are below

```
    <!--
    ===============================================================
    Page
    uses targets from page-impl.xml to generate the output markup
    file and associated microloader / app manifest
    ===============================================================
    -->
386:    <import file="${basedir}/.sencha/app/page-impl.xml"/>
387:    <target name="page" 
388:            depends="init" 
389:            description="Builds the application's HTML page.">
390:        <x-ant-call unless="skip.page">
391:            <target name="-before-page"/>
392:            <target name="-page"/>
393:            <target name="-after-page"/>
394:        </x-ant-call>
395:    </target>
```

The related page-impl.xml lines are below

```
201:    <target name="-copy-app-resources" depends="-init-compiler">
202:        <x-compile refid="${compiler.ref.id}">
203:            <![CDATA[
204:            app-resources
205:                -compress=${enable.resource.compression}
206:                -out=${build.dir}
207:            ]]>
208:        </x-compile>
209:    </target>
```

I found some reasons to occur the error. 
Can you explain this stack trace?

```
...
Caused by: com.sencha.exceptions.ExReflect: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sencha.util.ReflectionUtil.invoke(ReflectionUtil.java:148)
    at com.sencha.tools.compressors.yui.YuiCssCompressor.runYuiCompressor(YuiCssCompressor.java:58)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sencha.util.ReflectionUtil.invoke(ReflectionUtil.java:145)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Unknown Source)  
...
```

Comment: Did you add some custom css rules to your theme? If yes, remove all custom css and try to build it again. If it works, insert your css line for line until you know where it fails.